# ruby on rails 3.0 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, upgrade

hey, I wanted to upgrade to rails 3.0.
i followed the link below

http://oscardelben.com/install-rails-3

everything seemed to go smooth but finally....

---

gokul@gokul-laptop:~/Desktop$ rails -v

Rails 2.3.5

---

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can be sure if rails 3 installed with this:

in terminal, write:

```
gem list --local
```

and if it is install you can see it in rails gem package

Answer (score 1):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm

And cleanup all the previous mess ;)